# Visual Studio, Can't save onto a USB Flash Drive

Tags: c#

So, I've been having a problem with saving my **C# solutions** onto my **USB Flash Drive**. I can save on my computer no problem, I can drag the folder out and mess with it as I please, but once I put it on my Flash Drive, I cannot save any changes made to it through Visual Studio. 
I tried pressing the "Save" & "Save All" buttons many times, and they just don't seem to work. 
Then I tried messing with the properties, "adding a NuGet package", but then Visual Studio just gives me a:

> "**Save Failed**"
>
> > "Sharing violation on path /Volumes/ADATA UFD/2nd Year/Programming/Homework/firstObject/.#firstObject.csproj"

Comment: when you ***create the solution***, make sure to have it saved to your USB drive first.

Comment: i should also mention that when you move a solution and its folders, make sure to edit the paths in the `.csproj` file and any other file that has absolute paths

Comment: I tried what you just said, I made a new solution on my USB Drive, I pasted in some random code and tried to save it, but to no avail... :( Funnily enough, when I edit any other file through for example "Atom", let's say we edit a .html file, It saves completely fine...

Comment: does the new solution still give you the sharing violation error?

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately does :(

Comment: then it's very likely that either 1) the driver handling your USB was not properly downloaded (windows does this automatically, so something may have happened during that) or 2) your USB drive itself is missing some permissions.  check the drive (i.e. if it's the `D:` drive, check that drive's permissions)

Comment: you just need the solution save to USB for submission of homework? Try saving it into zip file before moving it to the USB.

Comment: That might not be the case, as I am on a mac :( and That's not it, I just like to have the file fully customisable as I am going to need to edit this directly in classes. So it would be best if I could directly edit this and save without a problem :)

Comment: try what **jmag** said and then tell us if it worked

Comment: I can save it into a zip file and save it onto the drive, I can do any saving and compressing and everything, so long as it's not through visual studio. I just cannot save any edits made to the file directly on the USB Flash Drive through Visual Studio, for some reason...

Comment: Do you have a different USB to try it on? and also check the data format of the USB

Comment: The format is FAT-32 and I'll try it with a different one

Comment: So, I just tried using a different Flash Drive, and It's completely the same thing :(

Comment: Maybe you try can asking for help from visual studio team. This might be a bug. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com

Comment: Do you happen to have IO stream in you code?

Comment: Nope, I do not have an IO Stream in my code :(

Comment: So, I reported this problem to Microsoft, Hopefully it'll be fixed? (\(^w^)/)